# How to make a truly improbable condition with limitations of Python's random?

Tags: python, random, probability, mersenne-twister

So I am trying to find a way to get a massively improbable condition based on random generations. To better explain, here's an example:

```py
from random import *
import ctypes

random1 = [randint(0, 2 ** 32 - 1) for j in range(10000000)]

while True:
    random2 = [randint(0, 2 ** 32 - 1) for i in range(10000000)]
    if set(random2) == set(random1):
        MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        MessageBox(None, 'Match', 'Output', 0)
        break
```

Because of the limitations and functionality of mersene twister, and the uniformity of its distribution of numbers, it's quite likely we will generate 10 milion numbers in both lists, where when order doesn't matter and duplicates are removed, they will match quite often.

This is not that rare, but the following code is slightly better:

```py
from random import *
import ctypes

while True:
    if random() == 0.0:
        MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        MessageBox(None, 'Match', 'Output', 0)
        break
```

This is a lot less likely to happen, but with massive single core performance, quite common today, it's still easily likely to get a match in 1~ day. The probability being 1/2^56, and with the limitations of mersenne twister in mind, it's not that unlikely to happen.

Is there a good way to write a condition utilizing randomness in python that will truly be extremely unlikely to happen?.. That would say, take a year to crack, or more.

Alternatively I thought to turn to hash matching... creating a random SHA256 hash, then generating random big data, and hashing it through sha256 to try and match the hash. But I don't know a way to observe probability in that case.

Comment: Your post is extremely confusing and I really have no idea what you're actually looking for, but if you want "better" randomness... just use SystemRandom instead of MT? It delegates to the system's CSPRNG so should be as random as possible". The randomness pickers of `secrets` use it by default so you could just use `secrets.randbits` or `secrets.randbelow` for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that existed.

Comment: FWIW you can also call `os.urandom(n)` with n being the number of random bytes you want (there may be limits as to how many bytes you can request at once, I know that e.g. `getentropy(2)` can only retrieve 256 bytes at a time but I don't know whether `os.urandom` loops), that's going to straight query the OS's CSPRNG without any abstraction in the middle. Then you can e.g. use `array.array` to parse that bunch of random bytes into random integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the *geometric distribution*, which counts the number of failures before the first success (some works say it counts that number plus the first success instead). As an example, the probability of getting no failures in a row is 1/2, one failure in a row is 1/4, two in a row is 1/8, three in a row is 1/16, and so on. If we take a zero-bit to mean failure and a one-bit to mean success, that means that with more zero-bits, it becomes less probable for that many zero-bits to be generated at random. As an example of an "improbable event", you can treat 30 or more zero-bits in a row as improbable.

Mersenne Twister and pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) in general have cycles. The size of this cycle affects how many zero-bits the PRNG can generate in a row. For example, Mersenne Twister has a cycle of 2^19937 - 1 numbers, so that in theory, it can cycle through all states except for the all-zeros state. Thus, it can generate no more than `19937 * 2` zero-bits in a row. (This is if we treat Mersenne Twister as outputting individual bits, rather than 32 bits, at a time.)

This is in contrast to [*nondeterministic* random number generators](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Nondeterministic_Sources_and_Seed_Generation) (RNGs), which don't have cycles but still generate random-behaving numbers. If the numbers it generates are independent, uniform, and random bits, then there is no telling how many zero-bits the RNG can randomly generate at most. One example of an RNG that uses nondeterminism is found in Python's `secrets` module, specifically `secrets.randbelow()`. (In practice, this module is likely to use a PRNG, but may gather "entropy" from nondeterministic sources from time to time, so that in practice the module's RNG is nondeterministic.)

Comment: Great answer, exactly the explanation I was looking for, thanks!